# How to block a function from being exported in MS VS C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

So for the sake of the argument, I have a module called ExportedFunctions.cpp whith a couple of functions decorated with the DLL_EXPORT (see below)

`#define DLL_EXPORT  __declspec(dllexport)`

ExportedFuncitons.cpp includes a LibraryFunctions.h. The functions declared in that header are implemented in LibraryFunctions.lib and statically linked to my project.

The problem is that when I compile my DLL and look at it using a dependency walker (depends.exe), I can see not only the functions exported by ExportedFunctions.cpp, but also all of the functions in LibraryFunctions.h.

That is the case even if I delete some function declarations from LibraryFunctions.h. They keep showing as DLL entry points. I want to hide them.

Comment: Have you tried using namespace { } (i.e. an anonymous namespace) ? While the functions may still be exported, it will be impossible to call them because scope resolution will never succeed.

Comment: Is it possible that you're building the library in debug-mode and/or Dependency Walker is picking up the debug symbols, which would allow it to show all of the functions (whether exported or not)?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The problem is that the lib file is exporting the functions. It looks like it exports regardless of what the .h file is saying.

Luckily I'm also the owner of LibraryFunctions, so I recompiled it using "Release - Static Lib". In that configuration I block the dllexport directive.